# Как сделать автоматическое одноразовое проигрывание видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Я делаю сайт. Я хочу, чтобы автоматом видео проигрывалось один раз. Если пользователь захотит, сам запустит видео еще раз.
Подскажете варианты? Сколько ни гуглил, не нашел ничего нужного.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Пользователей раздражает внезапно играющий звук при открытии вкладок. Поэтому производители браузеров запретили воспроизводить аудио, если пользователь не взаимодействовал с вкладкой, `autoplay` видео соответственно будет работать только в случае `muted` - тобишь без звука.

```
<video preload="auto" no-controls autoplay playsinline muted>
 <source src="/video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Comment: Данный ответ не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: И причем тут звук?

Comment: @Никита Не стоит вандализировать ответ. Будте конкретны с претензиями к его автору.

Comment: @Никита "И причем тут звук?" - пользователей раздражает внезапно играющий звук при открытии вкладок. Поэтому производители браузеров запретили воспроизводить аудио, если пользователь не взаимодействовал с вкладкой, `autoplay` видео соответственно будет работать только в случае `muted` - тобишь без звука.

Comment: Меня не интересует звук, меня ИНТЕРЕСУЕТ ОДНОРАЗОВОЕ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ проигрывание

Comment: @0xdb дополнил.

Comment: @Никита одноразовое автоматическое проигрывание возможно только `muted` видео.